# Alternative CSS option

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having a problem displaying the correct CSS when offering an alternative CSS.

I've got these two CSS files in my head section:

```
<link href="css1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link id="css2" href="css2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and this href in body:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('css2').href='css2.css'">Change</a>
```

The page is showing css2 (which has background-color set to green) but I want it to show css1(red), and then by clicking the css2 link it should change to css2.

Note: the CSS is working, each CSS file simply has a different background-color property.

Comment: How many times are you going to ask this today?

Comment: It IS a duplicate. They are by the same person

Comment: Well I think the reason that it's a duplicate is because the content is exactly the same, and not because it's the same person ;)

Comment: Sorry guys, chill out!

Answer (score 0):

your anchor should call a javascript function that adds

```
<link id="css2" href="css2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

dynamically to your document. In jquery this could be done like this:

```
$(document.body).append('<link href="css2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
```

Comment: Some people dont like jQuery i usually tell from the simple code they use. But i like your way also. The dollar sign and the syntax may scare them off but some people only want jQuery solution... anyways. Just trying to help out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="css1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="css1.css" id="css2"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and this href in body:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('css2').href='css2.css'">Change</a>
```

Comment: A [`<link>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) without a `href` attribute is invalid.

Comment: And no this is not going to load the css1.css file twice but just respect the previous comment. Thanks